# Anyone know what IDE settings Scott Guthrie is using?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, themes

I'm looking to modify my font's and colors to match what Scott Guthrie has. Has he posted this anywhere?

Comment: I can't believe someone just put scott-guthrie as a tag....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, the settings he uses are called ZenBurn which was paraded on Coding Horror by our own Mr Atwood. The colour scheme is available here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/exported-font-and-colors-zenburn.zip, the horror post is: [http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/09/is-your-ide-hot-or-not.html](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000682.html) and a screenshot is:

[image: Zenburn IDE image from Coding Horror]

Answer (score 1):

[I believe it's this.](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/textmate-theme-for-visual-studio-take-2/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [wekeroad.com](http://blog.wekeroad.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/codefile.gif))</sub>

Comment: That's the TextMate-style settings from Rob Conery.

Answer (score 0):

@GregD, I believe this is Scott's current scheme, at least the one you specified.

[Scott's Color Scheme](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/10/17/textmate-theme-for-visual-studio-take-2/)

I currently use it, I really enjoy it!